# ARM toolchain build

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-construction

I am building an ARM cross toolchain with GCC 4.6.3 using the sysroot approach. If I follow the LFS instructions and copy the gmp, mpfr and mpc source folders to the GCC source folder, the build will fail as mpc cannot locate mpfr even though the paths are correct.

The GCC build will complete without any errors when compiling gmp, mpfr and mpc manually as statically linked.

Now my question is if I should install gmp, mpfr and mpc to a random place in the toolchain build directory that gets deleted when the toolchain is finished, so they just are available for the different stages of GCC build or should I point the prefix at $SYSROOT so they become a permanent part of the toolchain? What is the most correct ting to do?

Answer (score 0):

I take a different approach with cross-compiler infrastructure. I have a directory: `$HOME/local`, with all the expected subdirs: `bin/, lib/, include/, etc.` `$HOME/local/bin` is (first) in my `$PATH`, and `$HOME/local/lib` in `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (or `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` on Darwin).

I then build and install gmp, mpfr, mpc, in `--prefix=$HOME/local`, with:

```
> ./configure --prefix=$HOME/local --enable-cxx [--disable-fft]
> ./configure --prefix=$HOME/local --with-gmp=$HOME/local
> ./configure --prefix=$HOME/local --with-mpfr=$HOME/local --with-gmp=$HOME/local
```

I can use fast, platform dependent flags for these packages, which generally don't work for gcc with a cross `--target` triple:

```
> env CFLAGS="-pipe -Wall -O2 -march=core2" CXXFLAGS="..." ./configure ...
```

The advantage is, wherever I build the cross compiler infrastructure, the gmp, mpfr, mpc libraries, includes, etc., are accessible - and the same libs can be used for more than one cross-compiler. i.e., I've got 4.6.x AVR, freestanding x86_64-pc-elf, ARM EABI. Each using the `gcc` configure options:

```
> --with-mpc=$HOME/local --with-mpfr=$HOME/local --with-gmp=$HOME/local
```

Obviously, when I fsck up a tool-chain build (I often do), at least I don't have to repeat this part of build.

Answer (score 0):

Building a cross compiler is a tedious task. Why not use [crosstool-NG](http://crosstool-ng.org/) to automate all the steps required to build a cross compiler?